# How do I draw a line on an image in R

Tags: r

This question is not about drawing lines in plots. I want to a function that will take effect on 2D matrices (or others) in the following way.

We have an initial matrix:

```
0 0 0  
0 0 0  
0 0 0
```

A line from (1,1) to (3,3) would produce the following:

```
1 0 0  
0 1 0  
0 0 1
```

A line from (1,2) to (3,1) would produce the following:

```
0 1 0  
0 1 0  
1 0 0
```

I know that I can code a function that does this, but I would like to avoid this.
Thx in advance.

Comment: Your "line" from (1,2) to (3,1) is not unique. Consider (1,2);(2,1);(3,1).    This is not a "line", it's a "path."  Please tell us what the actual problem is you're working on,  **not** how you want to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're trying to achieve this -

```
# coordinates
xmin = 1
xmax = 3
ymin = 2
ymax = 1
# resolution
howmanystepsx <- 3
howmanystepsy <- 3

# deciding which coordinates 'fall' on the path
dt <- data.frame(
  x = round(seq(from = xmin, to = xmax, length.out = howmanystepsx),0),
  y = round(seq(from = ymin, to = ymax, length.out = howmanystepsy),0)
)

# creating a grid
plotgrid <- matrix(nrow = max(xmax,xmin), ncol = max(ymax,ymin))

# marking points that 'fall' on the path
for ( i in seq(nrow(dt)))
{
  plotgrid[dt[i,'x'],dt[i,'y']] <- 1
}

plotgrid[is.na(plotgrid)] <- 0
```

Output:

```
> plotgrid
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    0    1
[3,]    1    0
```

Comment: Don't think you need `reshape2` there.

Comment: @Spacedman, you're right. Original thought process was to use `cast` on a more exhaustive data frame. Thanks~

Comment: Just posted an improved solution that uses the property of when you subscript a matrix with a two-column matrix...

Answer (score 1):

If you create `dt` as a matrix you can do it without the loop:

```
# coordinates
xmin = 1
xmax = 3
ymin = 2
ymax = 1
# resolution
howmanystepsx <- 3
howmanystepsy <- 3
dt=cbind(
   round(seq(from = xmin, to = xmax, length.out = howmanystepsx),0),
   round(seq(from = ymin, to = ymax, length.out = howmanystepsy),0))
plotgrid <- matrix(0,nrow = max(xmax,xmin), ncol = max(ymax,ymin))
```

then the magic:

```
plotgrid[dt]=0
plotgrid
```

I'm wondering if the Bresenham algorithm is what you are looking for though...

Comment: @Spacedman, nice. I haven't used matrices a lot and thought I could manage but clearly there's some way to go.

Comment: The two algorithms you posted do what I described and they work very  well. Do any of you (Spacedman and @Coderemifa) know if it is implemented as a standard R function or included in an R package?

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to post what I ended up using:

```
getLineCoor <- function (x1, y1, x2, y2) 
{
    steps <- max( abs(x1-x2), abs(y1-y2) ) + 1 
    return ( cbind(round(seq(x1, x2, length.out=steps) ,0),
                   round(seq(y1, y2, length.out=steps) ,0)) )
}
```

I needed to "+1" in the steps because in some cases the line was missing a coordinate (pixel).
Thx to both answers :).